# Change case of UIImagePickerController navigation bar items

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

**Disclaimer**: I realize this may not be approved by Apple, and I realize traversing the view hierarchy is programmatically unsafe. I'm trying to figure it out for my own curiosity :)

I'd like to change the case of a UIImagePickerController's navigation bar items.

This works for the title text:

```
viewController.navigationItem.title = [viewController.navigationItem.title uppercaseString];
```

But this doesn't work for the cancel button (clearly it's not the right location for the cancel button, but I can't find it in the view hierarchy).

How can I change the cancel button too?

```
[viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIBarButtonItem* btn, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    btn.title  = [btn.title lowercaseString];
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to access the existing cancel button, but you can replace it doing something like this:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{    
    // add done button to right side of nav bar
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"cancel"
                                                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                    target:self
                                                                    action:@selector(done:)];

    UINavigationBar *bar = navigationController.navigationBar;
    UINavigationItem *topItem;

    topItem = bar.topItem;
    topItem.rightBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
}
```

**EDIT:**

This will do what you want, I think:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    for (UIView *view in navigationController.navigationBar.subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)view;
            [btn setTitle:[btn.titleLabel.text lowercaseString] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh definitely, and that's actually what I intend to do likely. But I would like to grab the original string from the existing button so it'll all be pre-localized.

Comment: Ah. Well, perhaps you can divine the path to the button by adding a breakpoint and using `po [navigationController.view recursiveDescription]`.