# Add NavigationBarButton to UIImagePickerController navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to make iOS app and I want to add a UIBarButtonItem to a UIImagePickerController.
How can I do that?

[image: I wanna make just like that]

I tried too many navigaiton bar button operations but it doesn't work.

```
let sampleButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Example", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(sampleButtonHandle))
imagePicker.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = sampleButton
```

I tried this code but it doesn't work.

Comment: UIImagePickerController is a UINavigationController. You would need to update the navigation controller's navbar directly. Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27282497/change-case-of-uiimagepickercontroller-navigation-bar-items

Comment: It is objc i need swift

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm was pointing that out as an example you can follow. As a Swift developer it is important to be able to at least read Objective-C code to some degree. It's all the same APIs, just a different syntax.